# Sending data across Sockets may be too slow?

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi, ethernet

**Background**: I have a TCP Socket python script set up on a Raspberry Pi 4 to speak with an off-network machine.  The machine has commands set up that I send it a request over the socket essentially querying "What is the value of A?" and the machine response is the value of A.  While I am not super familiar with the coding of the machine, my understanding is that when queried in this way, it prints out the value.  I am receiving that data through the socket by simply putting a `socket.sendall("What is the value of A")` followed immediately by a `socket.recv(SIZE)`. My analogy is its like throwing a ball against the wall with one hand, and catching it with the other.  The connection is made with an Ethernet cable approximately 100ft long.

**Problem**: I can query across this socket quite a bit, up to the point that I can send 60 entry arrays back and forth between 5-10 times, but eventually, the connection closes up.  I'm not quite sure why this is.  It gets to the point where I have to unplug everything, close out all the sockets, and just give it some time before trying again. While it may not be clear to diagnose the problem without fully understanding the machine (which I can't really give more information about), I am leaning towards using threading to run the two processes independent: one thread to query, one thread to receive.  My guess would be that the `recv()` misses the proverbial ball, and then sits waiting to hear back from the machine, but the machine never talks again because the code is just left to wait. I don't have a lot of experience with threading, and therefore would appreciate some suggestions. Another thought is that the Ethernet cable is too long for the Pi to handle pushing that much data across.  This feels more naive, but I am not a network engineer and therefore don't claim to fully understand that process.

Thanks in advance, feel free to ask any clarifying questions.

Comment: Have you tried setting a timeout? [socket.timeout](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout)

Comment: I have not. Wouldn't a timeout just raise an exception if the machine didn't reach out? I would be worried about losing the data I was trying to gather.

Comment: Sounds like maybe a network reliability problem to me.  TCP should auto-resend after a dropped packet, but if too many packets are getting dropped too often, the transmission speed will be greatly reduced, as you saw.  I suggest trying it with a short, high quality cable and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Also try letting ping run for a while between the two devices and see if it reports packet loss.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I'll give those a try and report back.

Comment: What does "closes up" mean? If it's truly closed, that means packets with the RST flag.

Comment: I'd treat this as a network engineering problem, not a software development one. Start with `tcpdump` to capture actual ethernet frames (and the packets on top of them). Run it on both sides of the line if possible, and then you can see exactly when something sent from point-A fails to reach point-B, or shows up with a corrupt checksum, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because troubleshooting network reliability problems is outside the scope of software development (once the basic software-layer issues have been resolved -- choosing TCP instead of UDP, f/e, is one such, but you already did the right thing there).